# How to integrate ajax with jquery form validation plugin to check wheather email exists

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, validation

I have made my login form using PHP,MySql,bootstarp ,Jquery ,form validation plugin and AJAX and my form is perfect up to validation, also i successfully made 2 php scripts that checks user login email and password existence in database using AJAX ,  but what if i want to bring both AJAX responses i did in 2 separate AJAX files as a rule in form validation plugin ,How to add ajax as a rule for email existence purpose?

Any help is appreciated?

Here is my code

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
            /*function CheckEmail()
                {
                    fdata = $("#form1").serialize();
                    $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "CheckLogin.php",
                            data: fdata,
                            success: function(response)
                                                        { 
                                                            $("#LogErrmsg").addClass('ajaxerror').html(response);
                                                        }
                          });
                }
                function checkpass()
                {
                    fdata2 = $("#form1").serialize();
                    $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "Checkpass.php",
                            data: fdata2,
                            success: function(response)
                                                        { 
                                                            $("#LogErrmsg2").addClass('ajaxerror').html(response);
                                                        }
                          });

                }*/
    </script>

    <!-- Validate Plugin -->
 <script src="js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
 <style type="text/css">
        label.valid {
                     width: 24px;
                     height: 24px;
                     background: url(bootstrap/img/valid.png) center center no-repeat;
                     display: inline-block;
                     text-indent: -9999px;
                    }
        label.error {
                    font-weight: bold;
                    color: red;
                    padding: 2px 8px;
                    margin-top: 2px;
                    }
        form        {
                    position: relative;
                    margin: 15px;
                    padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
                    background-color:#fff;
                    border: 1px solid #ddd;
                    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
                    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
                    border-radius: 4px;

                    }
    .ajaxerror      {
                    font-style:italic;
                    color:red;
                    }
</style>
```

```
<form id="form1" action="User_Login.php" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Members Login</legend>

      <div>
         <div class="control-group" >
             <div id="LogErrmsg" class="controls"></div>
             <div id="LogErrmsg2" class="controls"></div>
         </div>    
         <div class="control-group"><label class="control-label" for="email">Email :</label>
              <div class="controls"><input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="input-xlarge" onBlur="CheckEmail()"size="32"></div>
         </div>

         <div class="control-group"><label class="control-label" for="password">Password :</label>
              <div class="controls"><input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="input-xlarge" size="32" onBlur="checkpass()"></div>
         </div>

         <div class="control-group">
              <div class="controls"><input type="checkbox" name="remember" class="input-xlarge" id="remember" > Remember me </div>
         </div>

          <div class="form-actions">
            <div><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-large" >LogIn</button></div>
          </div>  

            <div class="controls"><a href="ForgotPassword.php?mode=password">Forgot Password</a></div>


            <div class="controls">Not a member yet! <a href="User_Register.php"> Register</a></div>

     </div>

    </fieldset>
    <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function(){

                                 $('#form1').validate(
                                             {   

                                                 rules: {
                                                         email: {
                                                                 required: true,
                                                                 email: true


                                                             },
                                                         password: {

                                                                 required: true,

                                                                   }


                                                         },

                                                highlight: function(element) {
                                                                             $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('success').addClass('error');

                                                                             },
                                                success: function(element) {
                                                                             element
                                                                            .text('OK!').addClass('valid')
                                                                            .closest('.control-group').removeClass('error').addClass('success');
                                                                           }
                                                             });
                                        }); // end document.ready
  </script> 
</form>
```

Comment: So , is there any way i can show response in same place ,same style as does form validator plugin shows when it succeeds or fails their test?by adding some rule in $().validate() plugin so whenever if ajax sends msg that email does'nt recognized in DB .In addition ,i have also heard about remote option but no idea of using it ),please help i am stuck at this point. –

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkEmail(){
   $.ajax({
      url : 'ajax-url.php',
      type : 'POST',
      dataType : 'text',
      cache: false,
      data: data,
      success : function(text){
         alert(text+' was returned');
         console.log('returned');
      },
      error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
         alert('Error '+errorThrown);
      }
   });
}
$("#email").on({keyup: function(){checkEmail();}, blur: function(){checkEmail();});
```

Replace the `alert()` with however you're processing the validity of your fields. With Twitter Bootstrap, you can add the class `success` to `.control-group` surrounding the email field to give it a green border.

Comment: Thanks for reply but whatever you did here was already done as i mentioned in above code ,but my question is again (lets be more specific), If ajax file response sends that email is not in DB then i need this response to show up the same way Jquery from validator does (red lines across border of email field not anywhere else,but through above methods Jquery validator showing green lines alongwith right arrow pic(if it passes required and email validity test) but at the same time displaying error or success msg response it got from ajax file in red text to place whereever i mention.

Comment: So , is there any way i can show response in same place ,same style as does form validator plugin shows when it succeeds or fails their test?by adding some rule in $().validate() plugin so whenever if ajax sends msg that email does'nt recognized in DB .In addition ,i have also heard about remote option but no idea of using it ),please help i am stuck at this point.